# Does the Java 11 jar command support the classpath parameter?

Tags: java, jar, java-11, ocpjp

I am currently studying for the OCP Java 11 certification and I am currently playing around with the basic JDK commands.

In the study guide there's a review question mentioning that the `jar` command also supports the `-cp` option (the classpath). Is this true? I am not aware of such thing, neither did I find the information in the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867).

I know about the `-C` option, mentioning the path where the files to archive are located. Also, `java` and `javac` do accept `-cp`.

I am starting to believe it is an error in the study guide, but I wanted to double check first.

Is this valid?

```
jar -cf newJar.jar -cp /sample/dir .
```

This surely is:

```
jar -cf newJar.jar -C /sample/dir .
```

If the classpath parameter is indeed valid, what's the difference between -cp and -C? I am a bit confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run it and try yourself?

Comment: Yes. I have JDK 8 installed on the laptop I am using right now and my personal laptop is not within reach thus the question. This is the output for JDK 8: jar -cvf newJar.jar -classpath dir/ .
-classpath : no such file or directory

Comment: There may well be a typo in your study guide, or you have misread it (worth double checking). There is a `-p` option - but that is short for `--module-path` (and `jar --help` says *-p, --module-path          Location of module dependence for generating the hash*). So, `-cp` would be `-c` and `-p` for create an archive specifying a module path.

Comment: Nope, I didn't go into modules yet. Or (better said) my intent wasn't to use a module path. So I guess that's the explanation then. I must mention that I get the same output when using -classpath: `jar -cvf newJar.jar -classpath dir/ .
-classpath : no such file or directory`

Comment: What would be the expected effect of specifying a class path to the `jar` command?

Comment: @Holger I first assumed it is used to specify the location of the classes to be archived, but there's `-C` used for exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, the docs don't mention the class path, so there's no reason to assume that `-cp` specifies it (leaving aside that I don't even know what `jar` could use the class path for). Or does it? Or can other options be combined to `-cp`? How can we be sure? By looking at the code!

There are two classes involved in parsing command line options: [`Main`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee4bd700b772/src/jdk.jartool/share/classes/sun/tools/jar/Main.java) and [`GNUStyleCommandLineOptions`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee4bd700b772/src/jdk.jartool/share/classes/sun/tools/jar/GNUStyleOptions.java). Let's start with the latter.

In `GNUStyleOptions` the method [`parseOptions`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee4bd700b772/src/jdk.jartool/share/classes/sun/tools/jar/GNUStyleOptions.java#l272) parses the arguments:

```java
static int parseOptions(Main jartool, String[] args) throws BadArgs {
    int count = 0;

    // [...]

    // [ iterate over each argument ]
    for (; count < args.length; count++) {
        // [...]
        // [ get the option's name ]
        String name = args[count];
        // [...]
        // [ look up the option ]
        Option option = getOption(name);
        // [...]
    }

    return count;
}
```

Note that this code contains no functionality to tear combined options apart and `getOption` doesn't either - it just looks up strings in [a predefined array of recognized options](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee4bd700b772/src/jdk.jartool/share/classes/sun/tools/jar/GNUStyleOptions.java#l57). Since `-p`/`--module-path` is defined here, `-c` can't be combined with it to `-cp`.

Just for fun, let's check `Main`. There's `parseArgs`, which **does** [understand combined flags and switches over each individual letter](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ee4bd700b772/src/jdk.jartool/share/classes/sun/tools/jar/Main.java#l508). This is where you'll find `-c` and also a `-P`, so `-cP` might work. I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader.